# My monkeys are escaping

Tags: zoo-tycoon

In Zoo Tycoon you can't use chain link fences to hold apes and chimps. You can only use iron bars. However they still are escaping regardless of what type of fencing I use. (I stuck them in a dinosaur exhibit and they stayed). I need them for a Scenario and I don't want them to escape (I can't use dino exhibits in this scenario).

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which Zoo Tycoon is this?

Comment: @peper757 This would be the original. There is no such thing as chain link fence in the new one. I'll update the description of the tag when I have the time to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certain animals, such as monkeys, can escape by climbing trees or other objects next to their exhibit's fences. When dealing with these animals, make sure there's nothing next to the fence.